# Lambda expression usage with Selenium3 ExpectedCondition?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I've been using below code from last few years, How to use lambda expression to handle expected condition

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(getDriver())
                    .withTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .pollingEvery(5),TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(by));
```